# Show taxonomy list with taxonomy images ( SOLVED)

Tags: images, taxonomy, terms

i have a taxonomy list in the home page made with https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-categories-widget/ plugin .. i crated image field for taxonomies with ACF. i can show tax image on archive page but i cant show images of taxonomies on the list of taxonomies in home page. please help

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP Categories Widget
Plugin URI: http://www.mrwebsolution.in/
Description: It's a very simple plugin to display categories list in your website sidebar and you can define category list for your own custom taxonomy.
Author: MR Web Solution
Author URI: http://raghunathgurjar.wordpress.com
Version: 1.4
*/

/*  Copyright 2018-19  wp-categories-widget  (email : raghunath.0087@gmail.com)

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**************************************************************
                START CLASSS WpCategoriesWidget 
**************************************************************/
class WpCategoriesWidget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'wp_categories_widget', // Base ID
            __( 'WP Categories list', 'mrwebsolution' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Display categories list of all taxonomy post type', 'mrwebsolution' ), ) // Args
        );
        if(!is_admin())
        add_action('wcw_style',array($this,'wcw_style_func'));
        add_filter( "plugin_action_links_".plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), array(&$this,'wcw_add_settings_link') );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['wcw_title'] ) && !$instance['wcw_hide_title']) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['wcw_title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        // add css      
        do_action('wcw_style','wcw_style_func');
        /** return category list */
        if($instance['wcw_taxonomy_type']){
            $va_category_HTML ='<div class="ve-cat-widget-div">';
            $va_category_HTML .='<ul class="ve-cat-widget-listing">';
                $args_val = array( 'hide_empty=0' );                
                $excludeCat= $instance['wcw_selected_categories'] ? $instance['wcw_selected_categories'] : '';
                $wcw_action_on_cat= $instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] ? $instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] : '';
                if($excludeCat && $wcw_action_on_cat!='')
                $args_val[$wcw_action_on_cat] = $excludeCat;

                $terms = get_terms( $instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'], array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC','hide_empty'=>0 ));
                if ( $terms ) { 

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

                        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
                        continue;
                        }

                    $carrentActiveClass=''; 

                    if($term->taxonomy=='category' && is_category())
                    {
                      $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
                      if($thisCat->term_id == $term->term_id)
                        $carrentActiveClass='class="active-cat"';
                    }

                    if(is_tax())
                    {
                        $currentTermType = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
                        $termId= get_queried_object()->term_id;
                         if(is_tax($currentTermType) && $termId==$term->term_id)
                          $carrentActiveClass='class="active-cat"';
                    }

                        $va_category_HTML .='<li '.$carrentActiveClass.'><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        if (empty( $instance['wcw_hide_count'] )) {
                        $va_category_HTML .='<span class="post-count">'.$term->count.'</span>';
                        }
                        if ( $tax_img = get_field('4', $term->term_id)) {
    $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $tax_img);
}
                        $va_category_HTML .='</li>';
                    }
                }
            $va_category_HTML .='</ul></div>';
            echo $va_category_HTML;
            }   
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $wcw_title                  = ! empty( $instance['wcw_title'] ) ? $instance['wcw_title'] : esc_html__( 'WP Categories', 'virtualemployee' );
        $wcw_hide_title             = ! empty( $instance['wcw_hide_title'] ) ? $instance['wcw_hide_title'] : esc_html__( '', 'virtualemployee' );
        $wcw_taxonomy_type          = ! empty( $instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'] ) ? $instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'] : esc_html__( 'category', 'virtualemployee' );
        $wcw_selected_categories    = (! empty( $instance['wcw_selected_categories'] ) && ! empty( $instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] ) ) ? $instance['wcw_selected_categories'] : esc_html__( '', 'virtualemployee' );
        $wcw_action_on_cat          = ! empty( $instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] ) ? $instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] : esc_html__( '', 'virtualemployee' );
        $wcw_hide_count             = ! empty( $instance['wcw_hide_count'] ) ? $instance['wcw_hide_count'] : esc_html__( '', 'virtualemployee' );
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_title' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( esc_attr( 'Title:' ) ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $wcw_title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_hide_title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_hide_title' ) ); ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( $wcw_hide_title, 1 ); ?>>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_hide_title' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( esc_attr( 'Hide Title' ) ); ?> </label> 
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_taxonomy_type' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( esc_attr( 'Taxonomy Type:' ) ); ?></label> 
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_taxonomy_type' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_taxonomy_type' ) ); ?>">
                    <?php 
                    $args = array(
                      'public'   => true,
                      '_builtin' => false

                    ); 
                    $output = 'names'; // or objects
                    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
                    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
                    array_push($taxonomies,'category');
                    if ( $taxonomies ) {
                    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

                        echo '<option value="'.$taxonomy.'" '.selected($taxonomy,$wcw_taxonomy_type).'>'.$taxonomy.'</option>';
                    }
                    }

                ?>    
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_action_on_cat' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_action_on_cat' ) ); ?>">
           <option value="" <?php selected($wcw_action_on_cat,'' )?> >Show All Category:</option>       
           <option value="include" <?php selected($wcw_action_on_cat,'include' )?> >Include Selected Category:</option>       
           <option value="exclude" <?php selected($wcw_action_on_cat,'exclude' )?> >Exclude Selected Category:</option>
        </select> 
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_selected_categories' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_selected_categories' ) ); ?>[]" multiple>
                    <?php           
                    if($wcw_taxonomy_type){
                    $args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );
                    $terms = get_terms( $wcw_taxonomy_type, $args );
                    echo '<option value="" '.selected(true, in_array('',$wcw_selected_categories), false).'>None</option>';
                    if ( $terms ) {
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$term->term_id.'" '.selected(true, in_array($term->term_id,$wcw_selected_categories), false).'>'.$term->name.'</option>';
                    }

                    }
                }

                ?>    
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_hide_count' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'wcw_hide_count' ) ); ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( $wcw_hide_count, 1 ); ?>>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'wcw_hide_count' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( esc_attr( 'Hide Count' ) ); ?> </label> 
        </p>
        <p><a href="mailto:raghunath.0087@gmail.com">Contact to Author</a></p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['wcw_title']                  = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['wcw_title'] ) : '';
        $instance['wcw_hide_title']             = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_hide_title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['wcw_hide_title'] ) : '';
        $instance['wcw_taxonomy_type']          = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'] ) : '';
        $instance['wcw_selected_categories']    = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_selected_categories'] ) ) ? $new_instance['wcw_selected_categories'] : '';
        $instance['wcw_action_on_cat']          = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] ) ) ? $new_instance['wcw_action_on_cat'] : '';
        $instance['wcw_hide_count']             = ( ! empty( $new_instance['wcw_hide_count'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['wcw_hide_count'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
    /** plugin CSS **/
    function wcw_style_func_css()
    {
        $style='<style type="text/css">/* start wp categories widget CSS */.widget_wp_categories_widget{background:#fff; position:relative;}.wp_categories_widget h2{color:#4a5f6d;font-size:24px;font-weight:400;margin:0 0 25px;line-height:24px;text-transform:uppercase}.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li{font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #f0f0f0;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 35px;}.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li:last-child{border:none;}.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li a{display:inline-block;color:#007acc;transition:all .5s ease;-webkit-transition:all .5s ease;-ms-transition:all .5s ease;-moz-transition:all .5s ease}.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li a:hover,.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li.active-cat a,.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li.active-cat span.post-count{color:#ee546c}.ve-cat-widget-div ul.ve-cat-widget-listing li span.post-count{height: 30px;
    min-width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    color: #605f5f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 1px 3px rgba(0, 122, 204,.1);
    top: 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;}/* End category widget CSS*/</style>';
    echo $style;
    }
    function wcw_style_func()
    {
        add_action('wp_footer',array($this,'wcw_style_func_css'));
    }
    /** updtate plugins links using hooks**/
    // Add settings link to plugin list page in admin
    function wcw_add_settings_link( $links ) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="widgets.php">' . __( 'Settings Widget', 'mrwebsolution' ) . '</a> | <a href="mailto:raghunath.0087@gmail.com">' . __( 'Contact to Author', 'mrwebsolution' ) . '</a>';
        array_unshift( $links, $settings_link );
        return $links;
    }
}// class WpCategoriesWidget

// register WpCategoriesWidget widget
function register_wp_categories_widget() {
    register_widget( 'WpCategoriesWidget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_wp_categories_widget'); 
/**************************************************************
                END CLASSS WpCategoriesWidget 
**************************************************************/
```

Comment: Share the code please.
I'm  guessing your mistake maybe get_field( 'your-acf', 'mytax_22 );  /* 22 is the term id*/ /* mytax_ is the $term->taxonomy or you can use 'term_' */

Comment: i added code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the code that runs your widget will not let you add your image: [The code here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-categories-widget/trunk/wp-categories-widget.php#L101) shows that a loop is creating the unordered list and there are no filters where you can inject your own image.

You can add your own code to the plugin, but it's not recommended as once you push an update it will break. You may also be able to add some custom CSS that adds background images to a custom element inside the list tag. I created this [quick example](https://codepen.io/sixfoot3/pen/LorjoY) that may help.

```
.ve-cat-widget-listing li:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:140px;
    height:100px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/140x100); /*Will need to add dynamic image from ACF */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

**EDIT**
From my comment below, if you would rather edit the plugin directly you could add the ACF image field like this:

```
if ( $tax_img = get_field('YOUR_ACF_ID_HERE', $term->term_id)) {
    $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $tax_img);
}
```

Comment: yes i know .. 2 days i am trying to modify code... i solved "sort by post count"  but i can solve this taxonomy image problem.. please i not so good at php.. i can you add this code to the plugin  what would parse tax image made crated with ACF

Comment: If you don't care about editing the plugin, you could add something like the code below between lines 104 and 105 of the file I linked: ```if ( $tax_img = get_field('YOUR_ACF_ID_HERE', $term->term_id)) {
 $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $tax_img);
}```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Did you replace "YOUR_ACF_ID_HERE" with your ACF ID?

Comment: yet blank... nothing changed

Comment: yes i replaced YOUR_ACF_ID_HERE

Comment: thank you very much my problem fixed with your and others help

Answer (score 1):

my final code that worked quiet brilliant

```
$va_category_HTML .='<li '.$carrentActiveClass.'><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        $icon = get_field('firma_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
                        $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $icon);
                        if (empty( $instance['wcw_hide_count'] )) {
                        $va_category_HTML .='<span class="post-count">'.$term->count.'</span>';
                        }

                        $va_category_HTML .='</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want changes in this :--- `get_field('4', $term->term_id)`

If this `get_field('your_acf_field_slug_name', 'term_'.$term->term_id);` or `get_field('your_acf_field_slug',$term->term_id).`

You can use this reference also :--- `https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-custom-taxonomy-field-value/`

```
// Yours worked Answer

$icon = get_field('firma_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
```